# Git archive broken after moving from ext3 to FAT and back to ext3

Tags: git, file-permissions

I moved a git repository from ext3 to a fat32 usb pendrive and later back to another ext3 linux machine.

Now git does not recognize the repository anymore. My guesss is this could be caused by the changed filesystem permissions.

How can I make git recognize the structure as git archive again?

```
$ chmod -R 755 .git
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

EDIT:

```
$ ls -la|grep git
drwxr-xr-x   8 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 .git
$ ls -la .git
drwxr-xr-x   8 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 .
drwx------  32 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 branches
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mit mit     5 2011-02-12 21:07 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mit mit    92 2011-02-12 21:06 config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mit mit    73 2011-02-12 21:06 description
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mit mit    23 2011-02-12 21:06 head
drwxr-xr-x   2 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 hooks
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mit mit 52400 2011-02-12 21:06 index
drwxr-xr-x   2 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 info
drwxr-xr-x   3 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 logs
drwxr-xr-x 236 mit mit 32768 2011-02-12 21:07 objects
drwxr-xr-x   4 mit mit  4096 2011-02-12 21:07 refs
```

Comment: 755 makes all files executable, this may be strange for git. Try `chmod -R u+w` or something like this; I assume directories already have the `x` bit.

Comment: Does doing an `'ls -la'` show you the `.git` directory?

Comment: Are you sure it's a permissions issue and not a case issue? Can you `ls -l .git` ?

Comment: Sorry, I could have posted this from the beginning, I updated the question with ls -la output.

Comment: Actually it seems it is not a permission issue. I tried and changed permissions on a different test archive and it seems git does not care very much about the permissions under the .git folder. Something else must have gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `HEAD` has gone lowercase:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mit mit    23 2011-02-12 21:06 head
```

It shouldn't be executable but it shouldn't matter. Try renaming it: `mv .git/head .git/HEAD`.

Usually even case insensitive filesystems are case preserving so I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you, git likes the repo again now. I still did not find out what caused the case change. I actually copied 4 repos and all resulted with HEAD lowercase. All other uppercase files seem unchanged. I used midnight commander to copy the file trees.

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing happen when copying using a FAT file system.

Comment: I found 2 other filenames affected in the meantime, they were both less than 8 characters wide. Seems a FAT / 8.3 issue, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: @mit: That is very strange. Most modern FAT implementations supporting long filenames will preserve the case of even short filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happen recently when I did a Windows System Restore. My `.git/HEAD` file didn't get renamed, but its content got deleted. So I just opened it in a text editor and typed in `refs/heads/master`.